# Move iTunes data from Windows to Mac OS X (iBooks, Apps, Songs, everything)

Tags: windows, itunes, macbook-pro

I just got a MacBook Pro and I have my iPad and iPhone synced to my Windows. How can I move everything without any syncing problems. Or, is there a possible way to sync with both my Windows and MacBook while keeping my librarys synced at all times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that both machines are running the latest version of iTunes. Verify that iTunes on the Windows box is set to manage your files. Copy your library from yourusername\My Music\iTunes to the Mac. You're done.

Detailed directions for accomplishing this are everywhere; I thought that [these](http://www.macworld.com/article/146958/2010/03/move_itunes_windows_mac.html) looked pretty good.